# I'm new to react and redux, i'm trying to make add to cart using react, but i got error. 'TypeError: props.addToCartHandler is not a function'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**I'm trying to add data by using onnclick function**

[Here I made a product page from I send data to state using onclick fn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3l37.png)

[Here I made a handler to get data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhzeg.png)

Comment: It means addToCardHandler is not defined anywhere in parent, you need to pass as prop from parent.

Comment: You can put the code here using the `{}` option. Also, can you show us the component where you import and use the `Sugest` component?

Comment: It looks like you used `connect` to set `props.addToCartHandler` on the `Home` component but not on the `Sugest` component.